The Dart compiler exited unexpectedly issue after instal app on device or emulator
After updating on December 2024 Android Studio 2024.2.1 Patch 3 and Dart plugin 242.24931 and Flutter plugin I can't connect the Flutter app to the emulator.
I see this in the logs after installing app:
Lost connection to device.
the Dart compiler exited unexpectedly.

I tried flutter clean, recreating the emulator, and cleaning all caches, but it did not help.
Flutter doctor also show that everything is ok.
And suggestions how to fix it?

Try following these steps :

Press F1 to open the command palette

Run the Open User Settings (JSON) command

Add the following to the JSON: "dart.previewSdkDaps": false,


Reference from: https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code/issues/4726#issuecomment-1709827395
